# MySQL select current and previous column from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following columns in a table `tbl`:

```
    OrderID:     Parent:     Child:
    1              1           1
    2              2           1
    3              1           2
    4              1           1
    5              2           1
```

I wanted to get the current (`OrderID`,`Parent`,`Child`) and the `LOWER (OrderID,Parent,Child)` WHERE Parent and Child is equal to the current OrderID's Parent and Child.

So, for example if I have a query for `OrderID=4` the result should be the following:

```
OrderID:  Parent:    Child:
4            1         1
1            1         1
```

and `if OrderID=5`

```
OrderID:  Parent:    Child:
5           2           1
2           2           1
```

BTW, I can do this in PHP but I wanted to do it in a single query.

Comment: It was a typo. I just updated my question.

Comment: What should happen if order 3 is requested? What should happen if there are more than 2 matches?

Comment: Only one LOWER OrderID should display. If no LOWER OrderID, so just display the current OrderID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks all for your replies but I got my own answer.

```
SELECT a.OrderID,a.Parent,a.Child FROM tbl a 
JOIN (SELECT OrderID,Parent,Child FROM tbl WHERE OrderID={$OrderID}) b 
ON a.Parent=b.Parent 
AND a.Child=b.Child 
WHERE a.OrderId<=b.OrderID 
ORDER BY OrderID 
DESC LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Parent = (SELECT Parent FROM tbl WHERE OrderID = 4) 
    AND Child = (SELECT Child FROM tbl WHERE OrderID = 4)
```

And inside php fetch the rows to an array, search your OrderID and get the one before it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM FROM Orders WHERE  OrderID = 4
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM FROM Orders WHERE  Parent = 4 ORDER BY OrderID DESC Limit 1
```

Also if you hav time look at this answer of mine will give you a good demonstration.

[Finding free blocks of time in mysql and php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262260/finding-free-blocks-of-time-in-mysql-and-php/11264562#11264562)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM FROM Orders WHERE  OrderID = @orderId
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM FROM Orders WHERE  Parent = @orderId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
(SELECT OrderID, Parent, Child
FROM tbl
WHERE OrderID = 4)
UNION
(SELECT OrderID, Parent, Child
FROM tbl
WHERE Parent = (SELECT Parent FROM tbl WHERE OrderID = 4)
    AND Child = (SELECT Child FROM tbl WHERE OrderID = 4)
ORDER BY OrderID ASC LIMIT 1)
```

I'm not sure about the performance of this though...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
select B.* from 
    (select A.Parent,A.Child from `tbl` A
    where A.OrderID = 4) C
    inner join `tbl` B
on C.Parent = B.Parent
and C.Child = B.Child
order by B.OrderID desc
```